# Validate unknown number of textfields using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have defined text fields as follows:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="save_banners.php" onsubmit="return check_form();">
<input type=text name=banner[]>
<input type=text name=banner[]>
<input type=text name=banner[]>
<input type=text name=banner[]>
<input type=submit value="submit">

<script>
function check_form(){
alert (document.form1.banner[0].value);
}
</script>
```

How to access these fields in JavaScript? I am using the above JavaScript code, but it's not working.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the getElementsByName function:

```
var banners = document.getElementsByName('banner[]');
alert(banners[0].value);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// use <input type=text name=banner>        
var banner1= document.forms[0].banner;  
                                var len = banner1.length;
                                alert(len);

                               for(i=0;i<len;i++)
                                 {
               alert(document.forms[0].banner[i].value)



           }
           true
```

}